# PHP and ffmpeg on Ubuntu

Tags: server, php, ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg installed on Ubuntu Server and I'm running PHP from another webserver sending commands to the Ubuntu Server.

```php
$ff = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$file.'  -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s '.$RESOLUTION.' -vb '.$VB.'k -ac 2 -acodec aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -strict -2  -vf "movie=/datastore/logo/hello_logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=60:main_h-overlay_h-60 [out]"  /tmp/'.$MXF.'.mp4 -y';
if(!($tra= ssh2_exec($con,$ff))) {
    echo "failed to execute the Command";
}
else {
    $stream3 = ssh2_exec($con, $command_save);
    stream_set_blocking($tra, true);
    $tra_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($tra, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
    var_dump($tra_out);
    $file1=stream_get_contents($tra_out);
    var_dump($file1);
    echo $file1;
}
```

I'm having troubles passing the `$file` variable to ffmpeg.

Comment: Try double-quoting `$ff` in `ssh2_exec()`, altough I don't remember if this could be a problem. You have lots of spaces in `$ff`.

Comment: Also if `$file` (or any of the other variables you're expanding in `$ff`) contains spaces, double quote them in the command to send, otherwise they might break the `ffmpeg` command at the shell level: `$ff = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "'.$file.'" [...]'`

Comment: you mean all the Command i need to double quote ?

Comment: Put a `"` before each `'` before a variable and after each `'` after a variable, like in the example I wrote above

Comment: Do you mean for the whole command or just for the Input argument ?

Comment: I mean every time that you break out of the single quotes to concatenate a variable.  Look at my [example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638216/php-and-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment912180_638216).

Comment: You mean only before the variable

Comment: Nevermind. Can you post a sample of the content of the variable `$file`, `$RESOLUTION`, `$VB` and `$MXF`?

Comment: I have a starange issue going on with the code if I define the file path static and run the same command then it works fine but when I use $file variable ,which is a output of find command which I run through ssh2_exec and I have post and checked the value of $file .its get the correct file path but with $file command it give me always error and says vcodec not found

Comment: I have echoed all the variable and get the right value.

Comment: My set is that I have files stored on my server and I want to develope the web page where user just put the file I'd and then chose the bitrate and resolutions and can directly transcode the file .and for that I need to search the file via file I'd and I am using find command on the shell to search the file and then via ssh2_get _function defining the file path and this is the input of my ffpmeg code

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As per your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638216/php-and-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment912215_638216), `$file` contains a path output of `find`. That path is likely to contain spaces.

Using a path containing spaces in a command is likely to break it. So just enclose the path into double quotes:

```php
$ff = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "'.$file.'"  -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s '.$RESOLUTION.' -vb '.$VB.'k -ac 2 -acodec aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -strict -2  -vf "movie=/datastore/logo/hello_logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=60:main_h-overlay_h-60 [out]"  /tmp/'.$MXF.'.mp4 -y';
```

Comment: I have tried this code also but then I get the error message which says no file or directory

Comment: @SJ04 Can you post the path outputted by find?

Comment: /mnt/mediamanger/2013/2013-03/20130301-002.mxf
 
this is output of find command!

Comment: /mnt/mediamanger/2013/2013-03/20130301-002.mxf : No such file or directory 

this is error which i get from FFMPEG

Comment: $command ='find /mnt/mediamanger/'.$year.' -name '.$_POST['MXF'].'.mxf';
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $command))) {
                echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
            } else {
                 
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream,SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    $file = stream_get_contents($stream_out);
                echo $file;
    //$file;
    $ff = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "'.$file.'"

this is my code to find the file Path

Comment: Hi man ! Any tip for the input .I am really out of all possible thought about it

Comment: hi please any solution for this issue, will be really helpful